I have a Yixing teapot I would love to understand the seal
I wonder if anyone could translate this seal on this Yixing teapot! Thanks


"X勤花製", from a quick Google search the only artist that comes up is 高勤花. I struggle to interpret X as 高, the closest I can think of is taking the top part of 京 off.

Thank you so much!

These characters seem like the seal scripts(a Chinese calligraphic style from over 2800 years ago). So it may a little bit difficult to find out the current character today of these ancient characters.
The first character was rare to see and I don't know which character that evolved from it.
Then the second. The second had a left-right structure, and the right was 力 in seal scripts:

So we should try to find out the character with 力 in seal scripts and a left-right structure, and we got this one: 
The third had a 艸 on the top, and it could be tranformed to 艹 today. So we could search out characters with 艸 in seal scripts and 艹 in Chinese to compare the seal scripts to modern Chinese. So we could search out the character 花 and its own face  (by the way,  was just the correct character that 花 in seal scripts. For structural complexity and recognizability, artists today may more often use the structure of mordern Chinese with strokes in seal scripts style).
The forth. Because characters in seal was always used to recorded who made the thing the seal attached, the last character was always 制 which meant 'making sth'. Searching 制 in seal we could get this character:
So these characters could be "？勤花制". Then according to dROOOze's comment, the answer may be 高勤花制 which means the people 高勤花 made the teapot.

Thanks so much
